# LWC @wire decorator not getting response from controller class. how to verify response from controller class using @wire decorator in LWC?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, lwc, staticresource

I am new to LWC. Kindly help me.

I am trying to fetch value from controller class in LWC component.
But every time I try to fetch value from controller class, it comes as undefined.

Here is my code:
***controller class***

```
public without sharing class contactController {
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable= true)
    public static  String  getAccountExtId(String contactId){
        String accExtId;
        List <Contact> contactRecord = [select Account.CodeClientLEMS__c , AccountId from Contact where Id= :contactId];
        accExtId = contactRecord[0].Account.CodeClientLEMS__c;
        return accExtId;
    }
}
```

***.Js***

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import LOGO from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/CustomPortal_Logo";
import getAccountExtId from '@salesforce/apex/contactController.getAccountExtId';
export default class Logo_CustPotal extends LightningElement {
  @api  recordId;
  contacts;
  @wire(getAccountExtId,{contactId:'$recordId'})
  wiredAccount({ data, error }) 
  {
      if (data) {
          console.log('checking the data', data);
          this.contacts = data;
      } else if (error) {
          console.log('Something went wrong:', error);
      }
  }
coustomPortalLogo = LOGO + '/Logos/'+this.contacts+'.png';
}
```

***html***

```
    <template>
<lightning-card >
<div style="width: 15%; display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
   <img src={coustomPortalLogo}>
</div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. You sure you don't have any errors? Running as admin? Maybe you need to grant access to that class in profile/permission sets? Maybe you're running it on contact without account or one that doesn't have this field populated...

[image]

```apex
public with sharing class Stack73842936 {
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable= true)
    public static  String  getAccountExtId(String contactId){
        String accExtId;
        if(String.isNotBlank(contactId)){
            List <Contact> contactRecord = [select Account.Name from Contact where Id= :contactId];
            accExtId = contactRecord[0].Account.Name;
        }
        return accExtId;
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>{contacts}</lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getAccountExtId from '@salesforce/apex/Stack73842936.getAccountExtId';

export default class Stack73842936 extends LightningElement {
  @api  recordId;
  contacts;
  @wire(getAccountExtId,{contactId:'$recordId'})
  wiredAccount({ data, error }) 
  {
      if (data) {
          console.log('checking the data', data);
          this.contacts = data;
      } else if (error) {
          console.log('Something went wrong:', error);
      }
  }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Contact</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see you have used<target>lightning__RecordPage</target> . I need the value to be displayed in <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>. I even corrected the <targetConfigs>, but i encountered an error The 'objects' tag isn't supported for lightningCommunity__Page. Can you help me here.

Comment: Read the bit about "experience builder" in here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context. if for some reason it still doesn't work poke me again, as last resort we can try to read account id from the page URL in a "connected callback" function (acts bit like constructor or aura's doInit function)

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/261178/799

Comment: No luck. It seems like the LWC is not getting the response from controller class. Is there any other approach we can go with here? Every time the value for contacts is "undefined " for me.

Comment: Permissions? Does community user's profile / permset has right to execute this class? Any errors in browser's JS console or network traffic tab? Can that community user manually view that account (if it's his own accoun he should but different acc not neccessarily, you may need to read up on "sharing sets" or in extreme cases - mark the class as "without sharing")

Comment: what happens when you put debug logging on this user. can you see right account id entering the method or null or what. does it query and return 0 rows?